# 2013 Azure recommended Session State for multiple instances

Tags: azure

I'm looking for the current (2013) recommendation for Session State management on Windows Azure. There is a number of articles I found on the web but they reference older mythologies. I thought I found the latest method in [this Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278339.aspx) but when I went got to step 2 that says to setup Caching in Windows Azure Management Portal, it wasn't an option. I'm assume that there is a newer methodology that I just didn't see.

Here are my requirements:

1. All load balanced instances of the application can use a shared Session State.
2. That session state is not affected if one of the web role instances fails.

Basically I'm looking for the equivalent to out-of-process storage providers such as Session State Service or SQL Session State option that are used in non-Azure ASP.NET deployments.

One other concern I have to using the Cache is what are the scenarios when sessions are deleted? Normally I think of Cache as not guaranteed because of expiration and making room for newer cache items. I want to make sure sessions don't start to disappear because they are in Cache.

**UPDATES:**

1. I found [this Microsoft article](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/) and I'm going through the steps, it doesn't have a date last updated but seems to be recent. I'd still like to know if there is a better solution based on my requirements.
2. I found this [FAQ from Fall 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914142.aspx) that answers the question about the preferred Caching options.

Comment: Did you find anything on your concern if Cache is reliable and if sessions are not deleted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on the right track to use caching for shared state. Where caching gets confusing and temporal (as you have seen by different articles on different dates) is that what used to be called Azure caching is now called [Windows Azure Shared Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh697522.aspx). In October 2012, [Windows Azure Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914142.aspx) was released (as per the article you found) and is role (instance-based as opposed to shared) caching. Use the 'Caching' and not 'Shared Caching' as shared caching does not perform that well, is expensive, and generally replaced by (non-shared) caching. If you need it, shared caching is still available in the old Silverlight portal, which you get to by selecting 'Previous portal' on the drop-down menu on your name. Other features, such as reporting services, are currently only available in the 'previous portal'.

Comment: What do you mean by "shared caching does not perform that well"? Do you have any reliable numbers? I'm interesting in request latency, etc.

Comment: Nothing that I can share unfortunately. Non-shared caching has all but replaced the shared cache and is all that MS talks about in presentations. Think, for a moment, why with all the features needed on Azure, did they have to develop (and release before IaaS general availability) a new caching service?

Comment: What are possibilites to use a shared cache, without having the chance to use caching based upon worker roles and keeping performance in mind. Would a local cache per VM and a "sync" between all other VMs make any sense? So, that VM1 would notify all other VMs that they have to drop Cache-Item X (maybe by service bus)

Comment: The concept of 'sharing' that you seem to be wanting does exist in Azure Caching, provided all roles are using the same cluster. The cache then takes care of synchronizing data across each node in the cluster. You can also use [notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914137.aspx) to decide what to do with replaced/expired cache items. There should be no need do develop an additional sync/messaging layer for nodes within a single cluster

Comment: As I said that I use VMs (IaaS) instead of cloud deployments (worker roles, web roles, etc) I can't use the caching per deployment.

Comment: Then your first choice should be memcached. You can run it on each VM, or run two in a cluster and connect your apps to that. Two XS linux-based VMs with memcached will outperform and out-price ($18.72 per month) shared caching.

Answer (score 1):

We are using the October 2012, [Windows Azure Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914142.aspx).  We started using the co-located caching (cache cluster shared across each instance, but an azure data loss that brought down the storage container that our cache config was stored in caused an all day outage.

We just moved to using a dedicated cache role for our instances.  In this configuration, the cache config is only used on startup.  So far, the dedicated cache role has been working well.

Answer (score 0):

On September 3rd 2013 Microsoft announced a retirement of the existing "Shared Caching Service" in coordination with the announcement of the preview for "Windows Azure Cache". This service will be retired no later than August 29, 2014 as the Silverlight Portal used to manage Shared Caching will be decommissioned on March 31, 2014.

You can find out more of the new "Windows Azure Cache" here:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/cache/